# -Wtype-limits on attempt to limit an unsigned integer

Tags: c++, c, gcc

Consider the following example:

```c
unsigned short c = // ...
if (c > 0xfffful)
    c = 0xfffful;
```

Since `unsigned short` can actually be larger than 16 bits, I want to limit the value before `snprintf` it in hex format to a fixed-size buffer.

However, GCC (but not clang) gives a warning: `comparison is always false due to limited range of data type [-Wtype-limits]`.

Is it a bug in GCC or I missed something? I understand that on my machine `unsigned short` is exactly 16 bits, but it's not guaranteed to be so on other platforms.

Comment: @WhiZTiM: Yes, that is the premise of the question. Now the OP takes the same code onto a platform where `std::uint_least16_t` is greater than 16 bits. What happens?

Comment: I replaced `std::uint_least16_t` with `unsigned short` to avoid distraction (the problem is not in particular aliases form <cstdint>).

Comment: That's disappointing; I thought it was better before since you deliberately use `std::uint_least16_t` so that you can use specifically at least 16 bits (without the potential performance penalty of a fixed-width type). With an `unsigned short` I can't really see the benefit in what you're asking for. Oh well.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition The C standard is only defines the minimum ranges. I used `std::uint_least16_t` to show that I use the smallest int with at least 16 bits, which is also true for `unsigned short` (the fast one is `std::uint_fast16_t`).

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say it is *not* a bug. GCC is claiming `if (c > 0xfffful)` will always be false, which, on your machine, is true. GCC was smart enough to catch this, clang wasn't. *Good job GCC!*

On the other hand, GCC was not smart enough to notice that while it was always false on *your* machine, its not necessarily always false on *someone else's* machine. *Come on GCC!*

Note that in C++11, the `*_least##_t` types [appear](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) (I reserve the right to be proven wrong!) to be implemented by typedef. By the time GCC is running it's warning checks it likely has no clue that the original data type was `uint_least16_t`. If that is the case, the compiler would have no way of inferring that the comparison might be true on other systems. Changing GCC to remember what the original data type was might be extremely difficult. I'm not defending GCC's naive warning but suggesting why it might be hard to fix.

I'd be curious to see what the GCC guys say about this. Have you considered [filing an issue](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/) with them?

Comment: If you do file an issue, I'd be careful in your wording. I gave you a link to their bug reporting guide but I still maintain this isn't a bug per say. More of an overzealous warning.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem like a bug (*maybe* it could be deemed a slightly naive feature), but I can see why you'd want this code there for portability.

In the absence of any standard macros to tell you what the size of the type is on your platform (and there aren't any), I would probably have a step in my build process that works that out and passes it to your program as a `-D` definition.

e.g. in Make:

```
if ...
   CFLAGS += -DTRUNCATE_UINT16_LEAST_T
endif
```

then:

```
#ifdef TRUNCATE_UINT16_LEAST_T
    if (c > 0xfffful)
        c = 0xfffful;
#endif
```

with the Makefile conditional predicated on output from a step in `configure`, or the execution of some other C++ program that simply prints out `sizeof`s. Sadly that rules out cross-compiling.

Longer-term I propose suggesting more intelligent behaviour to the GCC guys, for when these particular type aliases are in use.

Comment: I found that using `>=` instead of `>` will silence the warning. Still, I think it's a bug: I'm trying to write portable and safe code, while GCC encourages me to do the opposite.

Comment: @danpla, that silences the issue because when `c=0xfffful` the if statement is true. The if statement is then no longer ALWAYS false. I think GCC is acting sanely if not smartly.

Comment: @chessofnerd Yes, that's the whole point of that workaround. However, it's still just a workaround, which looks a bit strange and not express my intent directly.

Comment: Note that with your work around, the issue would come back on 17 bit systems (which would be a terrible system but highlights that this isn't a general solution). This might be a case where it is appropriate to suppress the GCC warning.